# Лагает активити при скроллинге

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть `layout`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background">
</LinearLayout>
```

который находится внутри `RelativeLayout`, этот `RelativeLayout` находится внутри `ScrollView`. Программно создаю компоненты в этом леяуте. Компоненты разные (`TextView`, `EditText`, `Spinner` и т.д.). У этого леяута есть фон (простой фон с закругленными краями и обводкой в `1dp`). На эмуляторе все работает отлично, никаких лагов нет. Но стоит скинуть apk на девайс, как возникают 2 проблемы:

1. Если компонентов много (больше 20-ти) - то почему-то пропадает фон. Т.е его вообще как будто и не было.
2. Если компонентов не много (меньше 20-ти) - фон есть, но ужасно лагает при скроллинге. Сильно подвисает. Стоит добавить немного компонентов - как фон пропадает и ничего не лагает.

Почему так происходит? Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Почитай про [ListView](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/82-urok42-spisok-listview), коротко скажу что он держит в памяти только то что влезает на экран, а когда ты скролишь подгружает. У тебя же на экране сразу 20 штук, это моветон, а что если элементов будет штук 100? То что ты пытаешься сделать в корне не правильно.

Ещё интересно почему ты всё это программно делаешь?)

Придерживайся [GuideLine](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html), слева списочек всего.

Comment: компонентов очень много не будет. максимум 10-15. мне интересно, почему на эмуляторе не лагает, а на устройстве лагает? да и лаги появляются именно когда используется фон у леяута. там простейший фон, который имеет цвет, обводку в 1dp и закругленные углы.